What is the timeline for Cassandra 5.x GA release for commercial use?
I want to use the Vector Search  new feature that is added to Cassandra 5.0 with the Vector CQL data type . What is the timeline for Cassandra 5.x  GA release for commercial use ?

The project is working hard on getting the 5.0 release out. Unfortunately, there are still several tickets that are outstanding.  You can view the outstanding tickets on the Kanban board (Jira account required to access the board).
These need to be resolved before we can a cut a release candidate which is the step prior to the GA (general availability) release. Resolving/fixing the tickets is a community effort so it's difficult to predict when that will happen but the only thing that is certain is that the project is focused on getting it done as soon as possible.
For what it's worth. I've answered a similar question a few weeks ago here. Cheers!
